# How to create a sequence of pages/components with react?

Tags: reactjs, web, navigation, components, sequence

I am not quite sure wether this is a proper stack overflow kind of question but I really need some help and any would be appreciated.

I want to build a sequence of steps so the user can navigate through a certain flow of information. It should work most like an app does, but it is on the web.

```
           Screen B1 - Screen C1 - ...
         /
Screen A 
         \ 
           Screen B2 - Screen C2 - ...
```

What would be the best way to do this using react? Is there any lib that manages such a state or should I do it myself like using a higher order component?

Have already found out about [React Navigation on the Web](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/web-support/) using react native and I think this would be a good thing. But as the page states, it is a work in progress and not yet reliable.

Comment: If you're building for the web, the most common routing libraries are [react-router](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router#readme) and [react-location](https://react-location.tanstack.com/). Exactly what code to write depends heavily on your exact requirements, but those libraries will let you say "if the url = X, then show page Y", and you can use that to build your sequence of pages.

Comment: @NicholasTower And with react router I could do such like without making network requests?

Comment: As long as you don't need to fetch data, yes. Changing the url does not automatically mean making a network request.